# How to record action for automatic repeat in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, actions, batch-processing

I have repetitive actions I need to perform on images that are all consistent. 
For example I have 100 images with size 100 X 100

What I need to do on each one:
1. scale to 75 x 75
2. export as `png` ( with the same name )
3. close the original without saving

thanks !

Answer (score 8):

Gimp doesn't have actions on its own, but there are two very popular plugins or scripts you can use:

**Resizing using Bimp (Batch Image Manipulation Plugin)**

Source: http://www.alessandrofrancesconi.it/projects/bimp/

Instructions:

- Open BIMP from the File menu
- Add all the image files that you want to manipulate
- Choose Resize from the list of available effects and tools
- Apply

**Resizing using DBP**

Source: http://members.ozemail.com.au/~hodsond/dbp.html

Instructions:

- From the Filters menu in the main Gimp window (or Xtns in earlier versions), select Batch Process... to bring up the DBP window.
- In the Input page, Add your files and click Open
- In Processing, select Resize
- Choose PNG as Output

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/515726/gimp-record-actions) in Superuser has some other options as well.

Comment: Upvoted for citing my BIMP project ;)

Comment: When you have created such awesome plugin, get used to `becoming famous` :-)

Answer (score 7):

There is a fast way to accomplish your goal without creating your own script:

1. `File>Open` the first image
2. `File>Open as layers` the other images (this is one single action, since the file selector allows the selection of multiple images)
3. `Image>Scale image` to 75x75 to scale all layers together
4. Export all layers to individual files (some scripts available for this, for instance [ofn-export-layers](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/))

Answer (score 2):

To program repetitive tasks in GIMP, the official way is to use Script-Fu (https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-concepts-script-fu.html) or Python-Fu (https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-filters-python-fu.html)

In version 2.10, these can be found in the Filters menu.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/79346)

Comment: @Ovaryraptor: While this answer could certainly be improved by adding more detail, [it is not a link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/255554): If you remove the link, it is still an answer.